# Do kubernetes pods enter Terminating during or after preStop hook call

Tags: kubernetes

OK my real requirement is about graceful termination. I have a pod that implements a service via a grpc interface. Calls into the service can take some time - they are CPU intensive. All fairly good until a pod is recycled. What we want to happen is that we get no new traffic on a pod but any existing query continues to the end - we don't want immediate shutdown.

I've tried following the scheme in https://engineering.rakuten.today/post/graceful-k8s-delpoyments/ but without the SIGTERM handling. Perhaps I've misunderstood the reasoning for that and for the
preStop sleep call but at least my first understanding was the point of the sleep is to allow any existing calls to terminate. However in the kubernetes documentation it says:

> [If a container has a preStop hook configured, this hook runs before the container enters the Terminated state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-state-terminated)

Does that mean that the container enters Terminated state when the preSleep hook returns or sometime after it has been called, effectively concurrently? The distinction is important because (I understand) if the container is Terminated, then the pod will not be Ready and it should get no new traffic.

I am further contemplating making the scheme more complicated so that a file is created on preStop and if this file exists this readiness probe returns False - that should stop the traffic. However it seems wrong I should need to do this.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The idea that stackoverflow is specifically related to programming is I think dubious, or perhaps "programming" means something different to you. There are lots of posts with a kubernetes post of this site and some are on a similar topic. Many of my posts (and answers) are about build environments like Jenkins, so not technically programming. Nevertheless, if I am more likely to get an answer elsewhere I'll go there. I've cross posted to https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/18815

Comment: For the record, I've modified my pod definition so I touch a file before the sleep, and if this file exists any ReadinessProbe will fail. This seems to work fine but not 100% sure if it is needed. For now plan to keep.